# qTranslate-x navigation issue in language switcher

Tags: wordpress, navigation, qtranslate-x

I want to display translation menu with no flags and no titles. Something like this:

EN | IT

When i click on "EN" the URL goes to english version and when i click on "IT" goes to italian version.

I try everithing, but no solution.

Comment: You don't need to change permalink language right?

Comment: You can do this by using a cookie in php. Refer to this post: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42911/seo-redirect-on-first-page-site-com-site-com-en

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**qtrans_getLanguage()**](http://princessdesign.net/wpsnippets/qtranslate/) functions.

### Target specific language in the theme template:

```
if(qtrans_getLanguage() == "en"){ 
    // Enter YOUR ENGLISH LANGUAGE CODE    
}elseif(qtrans_getLanguage() == "it"){ 
    // ENTER YOUR ITALIAN LANGUAGE CODE    
}
```

---

### Different menus for different languages

```
<?php 
if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
          'menu-header-en' =&gt; 'Main Menu EN',
          'menu-header-it' =&gt; 'Main Menu IT',
        )
    );
} ?> 

// For menu calling
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(  'theme_location' => 'menu-header-' . qtrans_getLanguage() , 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want on mobile screen size or on desktop show the only one flag use this code

```
<?php   
if (qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'ro') {
  echo the_widget('qTranslateXWidget', array('type' => 'image', 'hide-title' => true) );
  print '<style> .qtranxs_image_ro{display:none;}</style>'; 
} elseif (qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'ru') {
   echo the_widget('qTranslateXWidget', array('type' => 'image', 'hide-title' => true) );
   print '<style>.qtranxs_image_ru{display:none;}</style>';
  }

?>
```